# Transparency of images in Outlook 2007/2010 and LotusNotes

Tags: html, email, outlook, transparency, lotus-notes

I have the following problem - I cannot render transparent images in Outlook 2007/2010 or  LotusNotes using the '`opacity`' CSS element (using `style='opacity: 0.4; filter: alpha;'`)  because it is not supported.

I didn't manage to find options in any of the clients that would allow for the rendering of the element either. Some options that come into my mind are:

1. Use another styling technique;
2. Render another transparent image from the original one and pass it to the content of the message;
3. Leave transparency (this is the least desired option).

Any suggestions would be of help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Transparency works but transparent images doesn't work in outlook
You can try this to achieve transparency

```
<style>
.bgemailfix
{
background-color:transparent
}
</style>
```